# Bootstrap angular datepicker ngbDatepicker doesnot overflow on the ngbPanelContent

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-datepicker

I have use the ngbDatepicker in the form as below

```
<ngb-panel>
              <ng-template ngbPanelTitle>
                <div class="row">
                  <ui-switch (change)="onChange($event,2)" [checked]="professionalLearningEvent.sportsPractive" size="small"></ui-switch>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <label class="accordianTitle" (click)="onAccordianTitleClick(2)">Will your sports practice be
                    affected ?</label>
                </div>
              </ng-template>
              <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
                <div class="container">

<div class="input-group">
  <input class="form-control" [formControl]="control" ngbDatepicker [dayTemplate]="getDayTemplate()" #d="ngbDatepicker" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': isFieldInvalid(control) }">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" (click)="d.toggle()" type="button">
      <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>

                </div>
              </ng-template>
            </ngb-panel>
```

The datepicker UI is not overflow. Try to find some solution but not able to.

[image: date picker]

Comment: I make a simple example in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-entwsq?file=app/app.module.ts and work. What version of ng-bootstrap are you using?

Comment: I am using "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^3.3.1",

Answer (score 10):

add `container='body'` to input element.

Example:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="dp" ngbDatepicker container="body">
```

[Github Link](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/1380#issuecomment-400645184)

Comment: In this case, by scrolling datepicker also moves.

Answer (score 5):

The issue was the overflow from the accordian card

Here is the solution just add the below css to override the bootstrap css

```
 .accordion .card {
      overflow: visible !important;
    }
```